# The duplicate answers flags are harder to process in the new dashboard

Tags: support, flag-dashboard

This is what we see when the duplicate answers auto flag is raised:

[image]

It's not immediately obvious that the same user (red) has posted the same answer to two (or more) questions. The "Answered x mins ago..." is buried in the flag between the details of the asker and the answer text. The asker's profile is also given equal weight. It doesn't matter who asked the question, for this flag they're not important.

This means I have to scan the list looking for multiple lines under the "duplicate answers (auto)" heading.

Can the answerer's details be made more prominent? Either made larger or placed on the right of the flag details box.

In this example the posts are consecutive but I've seen examples (which was also true in the old UI) where other answers were interspersed inbetween answers from the same user. This makes it even harder to spot whether someone is posting not just two duplicate answers but multiple duplicate answers. These cases are more likely to be spammy. Can all answers from the same user be posted consecutively.

Answer (score 4):

I've made a change, let me know if it's sufficient.

The default sort for the dashboard is to show posts with the most active flags first, followed by least to most recently flagged.  This doesn't really map to the way anyone would probably want to moderate duplicate questions.

Now, if you're just filtering to duplicates, we first group by flagged user and then sort my most to least recently flagged.

This should both solve your user matching problem and simplify handling because the most recently flagged will have the most complete list of duplicate answers.

Comment: I'll let you know once there are some duplicate answer flags to process.

Comment: Looks good, but the answerer's details could do to be more prominent.

Comment: Can the grouping by user be applied to the spam/rude or abusive page too. Then it'd be easier to spot if a someone was posting lots of spam.