# What does this guidance on the flag dashboard mean, and why is the text different when there are no active flags?

Tags: support, flags, moderator-tools, flag-dashboard, help-text

On the moderator flag dashboard page, when there are no flags, I see the following text on the right side (if I click the button labeled *Details* next to "Where should I start?" to expand this section):

> Start at the top. Because this list is only showing duplicate answer flags, the flags are grouped by target user and are shown from newest to oldest.

When there are one or more flags, I see this text instead:

> Start at the top. This list is ordered by the number of flags on the post, followed by the post with the oldest flags.

Could somebody please explain to me the meaning of both sentences? Especially the first one, when there are no flags to process at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text basically means what it says; it's guidance on how to process the information on this page, and info on how the flags on this page are sorted.

The more interesting issue to me is why the sorting is different for duplicate-answer flags vs. other flags.

I've found an MSE post that might explain this discrepancy; see (former dev) [Brian Nickel's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/330345/335251) to [The duplicate answers flags are harder to process in the new dashboard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330211/335251). In summary:

- By default, the page is sorted by number of flags on the post, then by how recent the flag was (for posts with the same number of flags). So by default, a post with 5 flags will appear before a post with 2 flags – but if there are multiple posts with 2 flags each, the more recent flag will be listed first.
- However, you can filter the flag dashboard to only show flags of a certain type – and one of those possible flag types is "duplicate answers (auto)". If you filter to only view duplicate answers, the default sort changes; it sorts the listed flags by the flagged user (i.e. the user who's posted the same answer on multiple posts) first, and then by how recent the flag is. So when you filter to only show this flag type, all duplicate answer auto-flags about the same user will be grouped together, and the most recent duplicate answer flag within each group will be shown before other duplicate answer flags about the same user.

Accordingly, the portion of the guidance you've quoted from that page is intended to change, depending on how the page is currently being sorted – which depends on whether or not you're filtering to only show "duplicate answers (auto)" flags.

But for some reason, the system currently treats an *empty* flag page (i.e. when there are zero flags) as if you're currently filtering to only show "duplicate answers (auto)" flags. That seems like a bug, and should probably be reported in a separate post.

Comment: It seems that in case of flag absence the help notice should look like "Firstly wait for a raised flag"